# Stop looping and output and then continue php

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

Ok, I think its time to ask here for my script now,

I have a large array and I want to loop it and then stop it when it comes to a certain amount and then continue to loop, here is a sample of the script,

```
$result_array = array();
$locations = //array of locations coming from a XML SOAP respond;

foreach($locations as $loctn){
    //Request of the XML,
    $result = //A large array coming from a XML SOAP respond;

    foreach($result as $val){
        $result_array[] = 'somkey' => $val->identifcator,
                          'somkey1' => $val->language,
                          'somkey2' => $val->textSubjectQualifier,
                          'somkey3' => $val->companyId,
                          //etc.
    }
}

print_r($result_array);
```

So the first array is from a XML respond and I loop it again with the locations and its requesting again from the XML and I loop it again into a different array and then I want to output the last array outside the loop,

But I'm having trouble here because its a very large array, and if the array not so big it comes out good but when I want to make it bigger then I got no result because the browser stops it,

I tried to play around with the memory but its not solving my problem so I guess the best way would be I should stop the array and then output it and then continue looping, but I don't know how to do it,

Please help me out with it

Thank you

Comment: This sounds like something that should probably be done on CLI side. Is that possible for you ? I guess the script is stopping, because of the max execution time is being reached(This value is usually found in the PHP.ini file(max_execution_time).

Comment: No, I thing I have to do something in the script it should be done here, because usually I know with my experience if I change something in the file than I found that I can do it in the script by self.

Comment: CLI means running the script on the command line. So you can still have the same script, but on the CLI side. It will allow you to run a script for a long time, which i think is what you require.

Comment: It's not clear why at loop `foreach($resustl as $val){` you don't use it's values.

Comment: It was a writing mistake, just fixed it,

Comment: try ini_set('max_execution_time', 0); on the top of your code, and see if it works :)

Comment: I tired it already this is not the solution! :) and I also tried `splFixedArray()` and this is also not the solution.

Comment: did you try to boost the memory limit ini_set('memory_limit', '100M'); ?

Comment: @ HamZa DzCyberDeV, yes I tried it too, doesn't work,

Answer (score 1):

```
echo str_repeat(' ', 4096); // you need this or something similar, because most of browsers don't print anything if they don't have enough to parse

foreach (...) {
...
    foreach (...) {
        ...
        print_r($result_array);
        flush(); // echo the buffer
    }
}
```

Sometimes browser won't display anything until it receives enough data, that's why there is str_repeat().

From the PHP manual:

> flush() may not be able to override the buffering scheme of your web
>   server and it has no effect on any client-side buffering in the
>   browser. [...]
>
> Server modules for Apache like mod_gzip may do buffering of their own
>   that will cause flush() to not result in data being sent immediately
>   to the client.
>
> **Even the browser may buffer its input before displaying it**. Netscape,
>   for example, buffers text until it receives an end-of-line or the
>   beginning of a tag, and it won't render tables until the tag of the
>   outermost table is seen.
>
> Some versions of Microsoft Internet Explorer will only start to
>   display the page after they have received 256 bytes of output, so you
>   may need to send extra whitespace before flushing to get those
>   browsers to display the page.

Trying to fix your code:

```
echo str_repeat(' ', 4096);
$result_array = array();
$locations = //array of locations coming from a XML SOAP respond;

foreach($locations as $loctn){
    //Request of the XML,
    $result = //A large array coming from a XML SOAP respond;

    foreach($result as $val){
        $result_array[] = 'somkey' => $val->identifcator,
                          'somkey1' => $val->language,
                          'somkey2' => $val->textSubjectQualifier,
                          'somkey3' => $val->companyId,
                          //etc.

        print_r($result_array);
        flush();
    }
}
```

This code should print $result_array each loop.

Comment: The `echo str_repeat(' ', 4096);` a different way, or it have to be with the whole script?

Comment: Why did you put the two foreach loops, do I have to put the flush function in the loop of my example, or I have to make another loop, and thats why I dont understand u made to foreach loops, thanks for you time,

Comment: I fixed again my post. The two foreach loops I put were YOUR foreach loops (without condition etc.) :)

Comment: Ok, I know that this works but I want to print it out outside the loop, and its not working, but I very appreciate your help, thank you so much,:)

Comment: Why you want to print outside your loop? Have you tried my code? I thought you wanted to print your $result_array each time you computed it, instead of waiting the end. Sorry :(

Comment: Yes I tried it, but the thing is that I want to do it outside the loop to make for another array there, I want to put the whole array int another array I should be able to sort it outside the loop how ever I want, but thanks anyways, and I would appreciated if you have another solution, :)

Comment: Well, you can call a function inside the loop...  First you said: "should stop the array and then output it", that's exactly what I suggested... so I'm confused :D

Comment: Yes I want to stop it and then output it outside the loop, so what function can I do to do that?

Comment: Some function that can output it... Instead of: print_r($result_array); flush(); - you should use: output_function($result_array); flush(); or maybe I didn't understand againd ^_^

Comment: Again, what exactly I want to do is, instead of outputting the result outside the loop at once I want to output it little by little and to put all outputs in another array, that's is exactly what I want to do, so flush is not good for it because this i can use just if I want to echo it, but in this case I dont want to echo it I want to put it in a new array, and the reason why I made `print_r` is because on that way I can see if it works or not, I hope you'll understand it better,

Answer (score 1):

> But I'm having trouble here because its a very large array, and if the array not so big it comes out good but when I want to make it bigger then I got no result because the browser stops it,

sounds like you're hitting the execution timeout (just as @Haroon mentioned). You might want to have a look at your error log or check if the request failed with status 500 (Internal Server Error).

[set_time_limit()](http://php.net/set_time_limit) allows you to (re)set the execution timeout as you please. But, if your script is running more than 30 seconds (which should be the default setting for execution timeout), you might want to investigate an alternate route of building that array.

---

```
foreach($locations as $loctn){
//Request of the XML,
$result = //A large array coming from a XML SOAP respond;
```

sounds like you're pulling data from a webservice. It also sounds like you might be (for a large set of items in `$locations`) be doing quite a number of requests on that webservice.

Accessing webservices may be slow. if you have any way of doing that outside your process ("job queue", something with cron job, …) do it. Also check if the data provided by the webservice can be cached and reused.

Comment: I tried several times the `set_time_limit()` function wasn't solve my problem, because when I put the `print_r()` function in the loop then its ok, the problem occurs when I put it outside the loop, and about the webservice I can make how many requests I want I tried it already too, Thanks anyways for you help, :)