# PHP How to respond to HTTP Request and continue processing?

Tags: php, http, response.redirect, http-status-code-200

I am working with an API for a payment gateway that does a callback request.
When the callback request is made, the gateway expects me to respond with "OK".
Nothing more or less. And that doesn't mean html rendered response. Just a callback file with those 2 letters. Note that doesn't mean it wants HTTP Status Code 200/OK... it wants actual data (not headers) for the word "OK".

So this won't work:

```
<html><body>OK</body></html>
```

This will work:

```
<?php echo "OK"; ?>
```

however, after I send back OK, I need to do some stuff on the server side and then redirect the browser page to another page. But when I try to do:

```
<?php
echo "OK";
header('Location: http://www.store.com/success.php');
exit;
?>
```

The gateway ignores the echo "OK" and instead reads the html off of the success.php page that I redirect to.

So how can I send back just the OK but continue doing things on my side?

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you send the `Location:` header first?

Comment: Afer you send something in the body you can not change/add a HTTP header.

Comment: Same result. It still gets the html of the redirect page

Comment: It seams you went wrong way, you should talk with gateway by services.

Comment: Is the redirect before the html tags?

Comment: Aren't you redirecting the API server rather than the user's browser there? I think the solution will be considerably more complicated than this, exactly how you do it depends on *exactly* what you are trying to do. I'm guess you will need to have the `OK` script log some data to a database, and have the browser poll the database for updates until this happens.

Comment: Why would you redirect a callback? Just handle the callback and echo OK as instructed.

Comment: If an API is calling your page, what is the purpose of redirecting the browser?  It sounds like they follow the redirect but still expect the `OK` response.  How much stuff do you need to do on your side (i.e. 1 second of processing of 5 minutes)?  If its short, just do it and then output OK, otherwise you will need to spawn off another process in the background.  If you use PHP-FPM, then you get the function `fastcgi_finish_request()` which lets you terminate the request and continue processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't send content then redirect.  The redirect header setting must be done alone.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. I had feared this.. ok.. I will try to talk to the gateway and ask them what they expect people should be doing in this case. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [`flush();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) to force php to write out the OK.

Comment: @powtac Look to this for flush(): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072717/stop-looping-and-output-and-then-continue-php/11072848#11072848

Answer (score 0):

Would it be acceptable to move the redirect into client side either with javascript or meta refresh tag?

Answer (score 0):

Before you send the `OK` you could call PHP via commandline to make PHP acting like multi threated.